Is there a simpler, more memory-efficient way to solve this 'magnet' problem?
This was my solution to the magnet problem, where you are given a number n and enter n lines of '10' or '01' magnets. Magnets connect with one another on opposite poles and you are tasked with returning a number g, or groups of magnets after they have all connected or not connected.
from itertools import tee

n = int(input())
magnets = []

for i in range(n):
    magnet = input()
    magnets.append(magnet)

def pairwise(iterable):
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

m = iter(magnets)

g = 1 # there will always be at least 1 group

for x, nxt in pairwise(m):
    if x != nxt:
        g += 1
    else:
        pass

print(g)

I'm not necessarily concerned with shortening this to the point of it being unreadable, I'm just curious if there is a simpler way to compare each i and i+1 in a simpler way.

Unrelated to your question but I don't think you handle the edge case of n = 0 correctly.

itertools.pairwise is in the standard library as of Python 3.10. else isn’t mandatory, so you don’t need to include else: pass.

Regarding memory: you don't have to store all magnets, just the previous one:
prev = None
groups = 0 

n = int(input("count: "))
for i in range(n):
    magnet = input("either 01 or 10: ")
    if magnet != prev:
        groups += 1
        prev = magnet

print(groups)


This is exactly what I was looking for. It also accounts for the first magnet looked at always being it's own group since it will be compared to None. Nice.

Start with the assumption that there are n groups, i.e., no connections. Reduce the count for every two consecutive magnets that in fact do connect.
n = int(input())
m = None
for _ in range(n):
    n -= m == (m := input())
print(n)

Attempt This Online!
